# Customised ObjectMapper not working with spring boot hateoas

Tags: rest, jackson, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I have developed an rest service using spring-boot and Spring-boot-starter hateoas. And I am facing an issue with customizing ObjectMapper. The code goes below for the same:

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@Import(BillServiceConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
@ComponentScan({"com.bill"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy-dd"));
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    builder.configure(objectMapper);
    return builder;
}
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
```

Bill.java:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonRootName("bills")
public class Bill{
```

BillController.java:

```
public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Bill>>> getBills(){
```

The output I am getting is:

```
{
_embedded: {
billList:
```

But I require "bills" in place of "billList". It is because of ObjectMapper is not getting customized. Am I missing any configuration, Kindly help me out in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How could `@JsonRootName` on `Bill` possibly have any influence on the property name `billList`?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever solve this?

Comment: A little more digging through the spring source code and some googling and I came across this which describes the issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/333

Answer (score 1):

I'm using spring-boot 1.5 RC1. If you remove the @EnableHypermediaSupport annotation spring-boot should configure spring-hateoas with ISO 8601 dates for you so long as you have java time module on the classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This worked for me anyway.

If you want further custom configuration see the solutions at http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/333

Answer (score 0):

Root of this problem - default ObjectMapper from Spring MVC is used instead of one configured by author.
This happens because of @EnableWebMvc.

Quote from [Spring Boot guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

> Normally you would add @EnableWebMvc for a Spring MVC app, but Spring
>   Boot adds it automatically when it sees spring-webmvc on the
>   classpath.

However if you one puts it, Spring MVC will create its own set of MessageConverters and won't use yours ObjectMapper.

PS even though I post this answer so late, may be it will help others.